# playwright Chromium browser not installed in heroku platform while deploying meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-java

We are deploying meteor app with nodejs in heroku platform.
meteor@1.9.2
Nodejs@1.14.1
Playwright@1.14.0
https://github.com/playwright-community/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git
https://github.com/sunny/chromium-buildpack.git
After deploying the app getting following error
[image]

after installed following command
npx playwright install.

But still same issue can anyone facing like this issue or give guidance thanks

Comment: can someone help me on this , i have tried several ways but no success.